# Type T is not defined

Tags: vb.net, generics

So I'm trying to create a generic expression which can be used across all my classes.

```
 Function Test(field As String) As Func(Of T, String)
        Dim xParam = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "o")
        Dim prop = Expression.Property(xParam, GetType(T).GetProperty(field))
        Dim lambda = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, String))(prop, xParam)
        Return lambda.Compile()
    End Function
```

However T is not defined. How can I use T with VB.NET?

Comment: `Function Test(Of T)(field As String) As Func(Of T, String)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the type variable. Change your method signature to:

```
Function Test(Of T)(field As String) As Func(Of T, String)
```